# How di i force date format to YYYY-MM-DD in a peace of code behind a userfirm in Excel

Tags: excel, date

In Cell B2 on sheet "Verzendlijst_PostNL"a date will be entered by TextBox: txtDate and then with filldown till the next Row with data. This works OK but i need the date to be forced to YYYY-MM-DD in the row excelsheet.
What code do i put where?
Thank You

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Set ws = Worksheets("Verzendlijst_PostNL")

ws.Range("B2") = txtDate.Value
ws.Range("J2") = txtDes.Value

LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B2:B" & LastRow).FillDown
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("J2:J" & LastRow).FillDown

Me.txtDate.Value = ""
Me.txtDes.Value = ""
Me.txtDate.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe `Range("B2:B" & LastRow).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"` ?

Comment: How about `Range("B2:B" & LastRow).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"`?

Comment: @Jeeped Great teamwork. You're taking care of colum `J` while my line is for column `B`. Of course, I was 30 seconds slower. But then again... who is faster than you?

Comment: @Ralph - If you post as an answer, include the **... where ...** portion of the original question.

Comment: @Ruud van Deursen - Is all of this taking place on the *Verzendlijst_PostNL* worksheet? Is the code on the *Verzendlijst_PostNL* worksheet code sheet? You are qualifying the parent of `ws.Range("B2")` but not `Cells(...`, `Range("B2:B", ....` etc.

Comment: Hello Petter,thanks for youe efford. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your problem in an Excel file and came up with the following (working) solution:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Verzendlijst_PostNL")

If IsDate(Me.txtDate.Value) Then
    ws.Range("B2").Value = CDate(Me.txtDate.Value)
Else
    ws.Range("B2").Value = Me.txtDate.Value
End If
If IsDate(Me.txtDes.Value) Then
    ws.Range("J2").Value = CDate(Me.txtDes.Value)
Else
    ws.Range("J2").Value = Me.txtDes.Value
End If

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("B2:B" & LastRow).FillDown
    ws.Range("J2:J" & LastRow).FillDown
    ws.Range("B2:B" & LastRow).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
    ws.Range("J2:J" & LastRow).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"

Me.txtDate.Value = ""
Me.txtDes.Value = ""
Me.txtDate.SetFocus

End Sub
```

[image]

Note:

The code is verifying that there is a recognizable date in the text box `txtDate` and `txtDesc`. Only if that's the case, VBA will attempt to convert the **TEXT** to an actual date. If that's not the case then VBA will insert the TEXT into the cells and - despite the date format - the values will be shown as (unrecognized) text.

Comment: Dear Ralph, you are the best. Works Perfect. Thank you so much and have a great day.